# How does Rx really work on web (client side)

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have gone through the introduction part at [Rx CodePlex](https://rx.codeplex.com/) page. I have watched the [video of the guy with CascadiaJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqBq4uoiG0M). I have discovered how the RxJS library is used. I have a question about how is it going to help me with my existing Ajax application and what do I have to change on server side as well as client-side to make the most of RxJS.

**Scenario**
I have a REST service written using ASP.NET Web API. The service currently has one method, it takes an array of coordinates and return another array of coordinates. So the call is very simple, it goes like this.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.myservice.com/service1/",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: handle_success,
    error: handle_failure,
    OPTIONS: null,
});
```

Now the above call simply calls a REST service and takes appropriate action on how the results come out.

With Rx, I heard the mantra of "Push" instead of Pull. How are we going to fit "Push" into the sample above ? Am I going to change my REST service to be a Listening TCP Socket which my webpage will stay connected (or make a Keep-Alive connection) and new values will be "Pushed". Or this would just be a service call as above, but the success/error will just be "channeled" through Observable and once the call is finished, the job of that Observable is finished ?

Comment: I found something related here http://rxjs.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#doc/howdoi/jquery.md

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even without worrying about changing your server to push to the client, RxJs can help you compose your asynchronous actions on the client.

For example, if you model your ajax call as an observable:

```
// each time you subscribe to service, it will execute the ajax call and send back the result
var service = Rx.Observable.defer(function () {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.myservice.com/service1/",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    });
});

// Now fun with Rx

// just call the service like in your OP example:
service.subscribe(handle_success, handle_failure);

// poll the service every 5 seconds
var pollInterval = Rx.Observable.empty().delay(5000);
service
    .concat(pollInterval)
    .repeat()
    .subscribe(success, failure);

// run the service whenever user clicks Refresh
$('#refresh')
    .onAsObservable('click')
    .flatMap(function () { return service; })
    .subscribe(success, failure);

// same as above, but ignore it when user clicks too fast (e.g. faster than 1 second)
$("#refresh")
    .onAsObservable('click')
    .debounce(1000)
    .flatMap(function () { return service; })
    .subscribe(success, failure);
```

Comment: why is it called debounce and not Throttle like in regular Rx ? and what does Empty return ? One single item or it is a continuous stream ?

Comment: It used to be called `throttle`, but a while ago it was pointed out that the operation performed by Rx `Throttle` is really what is commonly known as [debounce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce), and so it was changed to be less confusing to developers coming from other frameworks.  `empty` is an observable that completes immediately without producing any values.  I am using it in conjunction with `delay` (which delays the completion of empty) to insert a pause after the service completes and before it starts up again

Comment: I tried the pollInterval code, it is running only once. May be we have to use observable.interval or something

Comment: Did you use `defer`?  If so and it did not work then you would need to post your code, possibly as a new question.